Sample Codeql Query for SpringBootApplication
I am trying to learn Codeql analysis tool and running into some issues while running the query.
I am able to successfully create the database upon running the command:
 codeql database create

But when I run the query:
codeql query run db-name

I keep getting the error 'could not resolve the module java' but I see the java folder in the codeql that I had extracted after initial installation.
Any pointers to resolve this is highly appreciated.
Thank you
Here is a sample application I have:
@SpringBootApplication
public class myApplication{
  public satic void main (String args[]){
     SpringApplication.run(myApplication.class, args);
  }
}

And here is a sample query I found on github that I am trying to run. This is supposed to return classes annotated with SpringBootApplication
import java

class SpringBootApplication extends Class{
  SpringBootApplication(){
    exists(Annotation annot |
     annot.getType().getName() = "SpringBootApplication" and
     annot.getAnnotatedElement() = this
   )
  }
}


It doesn't looks like Java.

The original code is java using SpringBoot. I am assuming you are looking at the second code snippet which is codeql  query language that I am having issues with.

I was able to resolve it and here's how I did it:

Placed qlpack.yml file in my code repository with following contents:

name: java-queries
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  codeql/java-queries:*.*


Run the command : codeql pack install

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.
